# show only the last label in dataset of ios charts

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I have been trying to find how to add the last label to my chart as in this picture

[image]

The current status of my chart is the following:

[image]

My code is the following:

```
    //Remove labels from data set
    data.setDrawValues(false)

    //remove x axis labels
    self.priceChart!.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false

    // Remove left axis
    self.priceChart!.leftAxis.enabled = false
    self.priceChart!.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    self.priceChart!.leftAxis.spaceTop = 0.5
    self.priceChart!.leftAxis.startAtZeroEnabled = false
    self.priceChart!.leftAxis.spaceBottom = 0.4

    // Add right axis
    self.priceChart!.rightAxis.enabled = true
    self.priceChart!.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
    self.priceChart!.rightAxis.startAtZeroEnabled = false
    self.priceChart!.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    self.priceChart!.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
    self.priceChart!.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
    self.priceChart!.rightAxis.showOnlyMinMaxEnabled = true


    // Format right axis font
    self.priceChart!.rightAxis.labelFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)
    self.priceChart!.rightAxis.valueFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    self.priceChart!.rightAxis.valueFormatter?.maximumFractionDigits = 5


    self.priceChart.borderLineWidth = 0
    self.priceChart.legend.enabled = false


    self.priceChart.data = data
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

well you have to write additional methods to do so.

Currently the library does not support it. You can easily add methods in your `drawRect` to add it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ended up highlighting the last value and drawing a marker at location of that value using the ChartViewDelegate. Don't know if that is the best way to do it but it is working fine on my chart.